# Problem writing a matrix equation

Tags: equations, errors, matrices, tex-core

I write this code in order to get Newton's Second Law in a matrix form. But for some reason if i write the first matrix alone everything is ok. But if i add the "`\quad`" and/or the other matrix the compiler loses it and brings up error. After that even if I deleted whatever I added, that is I leave only the first matrix, it does not compile anymore and brings up the same errors as before. I have also tried with "`\begin{equation}`" and with dummy matrices. From the error reports there seems to by `$` missing that the compiler add by itself. Can anybody see what the problem is? Thank you
**Note**: *I have called all the packages necessary*.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{bmatrix} 
        m \bm{I}_{3x3} & \bm{0}_{3x3} \\
        \bm{0}_{3x3} & \bm{I} 
        \end{bmatrix}
        
        \quad
    
        \begin{bmatrix} 
        \bm{\dot{V}}_{B} \\
        \bm{\dot{\omega}}_{B}
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation*}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! There should be no blank line inside the `equation` environment. Unrelated, but `bm` should be loaded after `amsmath`.

Comment: @egreg You beat me when I'm writing the code...ahahah :-) +1.

Answer (score 2):

No blank lines in [math-mode](/questions/tagged/math-mode).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix} 
m \bm{I}_{3\times 3} & \bm{0}_{3\times 3} \\
\bm{0}_{3x3} & \bm{I} 
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\begin{bmatrix} 
\bm{\dot{V}}_{B} \\
\bm{\dot{\omega}}_{B}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]